# How to create a Tree Chart in Apache Superset

Tags: visualization, dashboard, apache-superset

I am trying to create a **Tree Chart** in Superset, but really not sure why there is nothing getting created on screen. I am putting the sample data which I have and chart setting. What am I going wrong here?

I just want to show all targets originating as branches from source

[image]